# How to get the array output without change order?

Tags: tcl

I get an array:

```
array set arrayA {1 a 3 b 2 x 4 g}
```

how can i get the output without change the order?

```
foreach {key value} [array get arrayA] {
    puts $key
    puts $value
}
```

how to get below output, thanks!

```
1
a
3
b
2
x
4
g
```

Answer (score 1):

Tcl arrays do not preserve the insertion order of their elements (dicts do, however). To list the elements in order you need to provide the desired order, e.g. by sorting:

```
set my_order [lsort -integer [array names arrayA]]
foreach key $my_order {
    puts $key
    puts $arrayA($key)
}
```

But that's not what you want.

You can preserve the insertion order of an array the quick and dirty way by storing the names at the time of creation (and updating the list of names when new names are added):

```
set my_order {1 3 2 4}
array set arrayA {1 a 3 b 2 x 4 g}

foreach key $my_order {
    puts $key
    puts $arrayA($key)
}
```

The less quick and dirty and more elaborate and robust way is to use traces.

Here's one way to keep order of an array's insertion order using traces. Traces can be set up to fire (run a handler) for *array* operations (calling the `array` command on the array), *read* operations (e.g. `puts $arrayA(1)`), we won't bother with those, *write* operations (e.g. `array set arrayA {1 z}` or `set arrayA(1) z`, and *unset* operations (e.g. `unset array(1)`). The most interesting operations for us are *write* operations, which potentially add new elements to the array, and *unset* operations, which take them out.

We can have one handler for each operation, or one big handler for them all; I'll choose the latter.

```
proc arrayOrder {varName name1 name2 op} {
    # make 'var' a link to the global variable named in the first argument
    upvar #0 $varName var
    # the three following arguments will be supplied when the trace fires:
    # 'name2' is the element name, and 'op' is the operation (array, write, or
    # unset)
    #
    # not doing anything particular with $op eq "array": you might want to
    # experiment with it to see if you have use for it
    if {$op eq "write"} {
        # is the name already in the order list?
        if {$name2 ni $var} {
            # no, it isn't, meaning it's a new element that should be added to
            # the order list
            lappend var $name2
        }
    }
    if {$op eq "unset"} {
        if {$name2 eq {}} {
            # the whole array was unset: empty the order list
            set var {}
        } else {
            # just one element was unset: remove the name from the order list
            set idx [lsearch -exact $var $name2]
            set var [lreplace $var $idx $idx]
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that takes care of the most essential matters. Now the trace itself is to be set up. Note that the trace is set up for one variable, in this case for three different operations. If something happens to the variable that matches one or more of these operations, the handler will be called once for each. We use a fixed first argument to tell the handler which variable holds the insertion order.

```
trace add variable arrayA {array write unset} {arrayOrder arrayA_order}
```

Now we can create the array and add or delete members in it, and print the elements in insertion order like this:

```
foreach key $arrayA_order {
    puts $key
    puts $arrayA($key)
}
```

Note that if you unset the whole array, the trace goes away and you need to reinstate it.

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm),
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm),
[unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the answer so clearly and exhaustive，I've learned more than what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says, dictionaries preserve order:

```
set d [dict create {*}{1 a 3 b 2 x 4 g}]
dict for {key value} $d {puts $key; puts $value}
```